# Bundle Fonts Into An AppleScriptObjC App

Tags: xcode, fonts, applescript, applescript-objc

Is the process for embedding a custom font different with Cocoa-AppleScript apps?

I have a label that would display a string in this custom font, but it is still defaulting to the system font when packaged and run on a mac that doesn't already have the font installed.

I've dragged the font (ConnectCode39.ttf) to the sidebar in Xcode, and ensured that the app is ticked under target membership.

I've even added `Fonts provided by application` - `CCode39.ttf` (The true name of the font, not the file) to the info.plist, although I'm not sure if I still need to do that with the latest Xcode?

I've confirmed that the .ttf file is in the 'Copy Bundled Resources' as well.

The label is currently set to use 'CCode39', although is this picking it up from my Mac's font library?  If so, how do I change it to use the bundled copy of the font?  Or is this part ok and there's something else I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: did you set the `ATSApplicationFontsPath` key in Info.plist properly?

Comment: I've just added in 'Application Fonts Resource Path - CCode39.ttf' but the label defaults to system font.  How do I assign it to the embedded font?

Comment: It's ok, I realised I needed to add label's setFont_() and its working now.  Thanks!